# what is the Cardinality of subsets of Z of size 3

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to find out the cardinality of the subsets of Z of size 3,

|N| = א0
|R| = א, thats how we defined it in class.

My idea is to build a ZxZ matrix, we can see that the subsets of size 2 are all under the main diagonal.
now we can build a path and for each step we name the current element we standing on the number of the step, we get a 1:1 and onto function from N --> ZxZ and we can conclude that the cardinality of the subsets of Z of size 2 is א0,

now we take all those ZxZ pairs we walked on and place them on another matrix Z x (ZxZ),
and now we can make a new path, but the problem I encounter is that there are many many repetitions and elements such as (-1,-1,0) that cant be a subset.

can i ignore them and say : we number only valid and not seen already subsets?
or is this approach not logical in the first place?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The punchline is that there are indeed countably many.  One easier to explain approach is to organize based on the largest absolute-value of a number present in each set.  $\{-1,0,1\}$ is first in our list.  Then we have $\{-2,-1,0\},\{-2,-1,1\},\{-2,-1,2\},\{-2,0,1\},\{-2,0,2\},\{-2,1,2\},\{-1,0,2\},\{-1,1,2\},\{0,1,2\}$.  Next we move on to listing those with largest absolute-value equal to $3$, and so this is $\{-3,-2,-1\},\dots,\{1,2,3\}$ of which there are $25$ of them possible.  Continuing in this fashion, we increase our total by only a finite amount each step.

Answer (score 3):

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $S_n$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb Z$ with size $3$ where the largest absolute value of any element is $n$. For example, $S_1$ only contains $\{-1,0,1\}$, while $S_2$ has these nine subsets:
$$
\{-2,-1,0\},\{-2,-1,1\},\{-2,0,1\},\\
\{-1,0,2\},\{-1,1,2\},\{0,1,2\},\\
\{-2,-1,2\},\{-2,0,2\},\{-2,1,2\}
$$
Note that every size-three subset of $\mathbb Z$ appears in exactly one of the $S_n$ sets. Therefore, you can get an enumeration of all of the size-three subsets of $\mathbb Z$ by listing the elements of $S_1$, then listing the elements of $S_2$ after that, then listing the elements of $S_3$ after that, and so on ad infinitum. In particular, this proves there are countably many such subsets.

In general, writing a set $S$ as a countable union of finite sets is a good way to prove that $S$ is countable. This technique avoids the difficulty of explicitly describing a bijection with $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the standard trick
of mapping
$\{a_i\}$
into $\prod p_i^{a_i}$
where the $p_i$
are the primes
to show that the cardinality
of the finite subsets of Z
is countable.